# iosart2x document class and greek letters

Tags: compiling

I'm attempting to submit an article to http://www.computability.de/journal/ and i'm in the process of converting my initial write up to work with the provided latex template. They require the use of their document class iosart2x and their template. I'm having trouble getting the template to compile when I copy in the body of my document. After some experimentation, it seems to be complaining about lower-case greek letters (the upper-case ones work fine). Anyone have a clue as to what is going on and how to fix it?

Even in the simplest example

```
\documentclass{iosart2x}

\begin{document}

$\alpha$

\end{document}
```

Update: So it seems that the document class is using breakurl, and I was attempting to compile with pdfLaTeX. However after trying to complie with LaTeX the greek letters get replaced with nonsense characters.

2nd Update: The message I get is

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "WriteupComputability".tex

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hope

fully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\jimbo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.

log

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\jimbo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Process exited with error(s)
```

The pertinant part of make-mf is

```
2019-08-14 14:50:40,967-0400 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --verbose rtxmi
2019-08-14 14:50:40,976-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The rtxmi source file could not be found.
2019-08-14 14:50:40,976-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The rtxmi source file could not be found.
2019-08-14 14:50:40,977-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2019-08-14 14:50:40,977-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2019-08-14 14:50:40,977-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
```

and make-pf

```
2019-08-14 14:50:40,711-0400 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose rtxmi 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2019-08-14 14:50:40,716-0400 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font rtxmi at 600 DPI...
2019-08-14 14:50:40,723-0400 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2019-08-14 14:50:40,726-0400 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2019-08-14 14:50:40,726-0400 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --verbose rtxmi
2019-08-14 14:50:41,007-0400 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
2019-08-14 14:50:41,007-0400 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer -q -t rtxmi
2019-08-14 14:50:41,258-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font rtxmi could not be created.
2019-08-14 14:50:41,258-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font rtxmi could not be created.
2019-08-14 14:50:41,258-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2019-08-14 14:50:41,258-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2019-08-14 14:50:41,258-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
```

I don't really know what this means, but I googled rtxmi and people suggested updating the FNDB, which I have done a number of times without success.

Comment: Please provide a small example document that shows the issue, in this case a mostly empty document with this documentclass and a few greek letters should be sufficient. Also include the error messages that you get in the question. When you do these two things it helps to be able to reproduce the issue en to try to find a solution - without it we can only guess.

Comment: also don't just say latex "complains" show the complete error message from the log file, in a code section (`{}` button) so that line endings in the message are preserved.

Comment: I downloaded the package and tried adding Greek letters in the provided template, with no problem.

Comment: I tried your example and get no error and an alpha; loading `breakurl` with pdflatex just issues an innocuous warning.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for trying. I'll try updating everything on my end and see if it works.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: I still can't get it working on my home computer, but it was fine on my work computer so not really fixed but worked around.